# Boostrap - form-inline with label on the left and input on the right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have inline form, in which for each line I want to have label on the left side, and input on the right side. I have tried `pull-right`, `align-right`, `text-right`, but none of them works.

[Fiddle is here !](http://www.bootply.com/O2RudXW9Zl)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I do:

```
<style>
  .form-group label{
      text-align: left!important;
    }
</style>

<form action="" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="FirstName">First name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label pull-left" for="LastName">Last name</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input class="form-control" id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="" />

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Well, that was my first thought, unfortunately I had the same issue as you have right now - your label is not aligned vertically with input field :)